# Determine all Laurent Series for $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 + 2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am given $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 + 2}$ and asked to provide all Laurent series around the point $z_{0} = 0$.

I've decomposed this into a partial fraction by having, $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{(z-i\sqrt2)} - \frac{1}{(z+i\sqrt2)})$.

Basically from here I'm lost. I know I have a break at $i\sqrt2$. So $0<|z|<i\sqrt2$ and $i\sqrt2<|z|<\infty$?

Apologies, I am not familiar with formatting on here.

Answer (score 1):

For $\|z\| > \sqrt{2}$, 
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z^2+2}&= \frac{1}{z^2}\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{2}{z^2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{2}{z^2}\right)^n.
\end{align*}
$$
For $\|z\| < \sqrt{2}$, $f(z)$ is analytic and has a Taylor's power series representation, 
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z^2+2}&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{z^2}{2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)^n.
\end{align*}
$$